# Issue with overflow:hidden/visible toggle on hover. Gif available in post

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

As you can see above, I cannot select the overflowed events on the calendar date. It looks like it's because I have the **`overflow:hidden/visible`** toggle triggering on the class of the calendar **`date: '#cell-shell'`**.

Here is the HTML code for that specific date:

```
<td>
  <div id="09" class="cell-shell>
    <div class="date-num">9</div>
    <div class="event-wrap>
        <span></span> <!--these hold edit buttons when editor is logged in-->
        <span></span>
        <div id="e1" class="cell-data">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-wrap>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <div id="e2" class="cell-data">Event 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-wrap>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <div id="e3" class="cell-data">Event 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-wrap>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <div id="e4" class="cell-data">Event 4</div>
    </div>
    ... <!-- pattern repeats-->
  </div>
</td>
```

Here is my current relevant CSS:

```
.cell-shell {
    height: 152px;
    width: 152px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cell-shell:hover {
    overflow:visible;
}

.event-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
}

.event-wrap:hover {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Is there any way through **CSS** or JS that I can prioritize the **`'#cell-data'`** elements? I need to be able to click on those events 6 & 7 and beyond, but once my mouse wanders out of the '9' '.cell-shell' box into the '16' '.cell-shell' box, '16' seems to take over.

EDIT: I added more information as requested by david. I thought it was irrelevant but perhaps not. I added the  elements as well as the  children below them. I also added in the event-wrap CSS

Comment: can you post any other css? i test the code and it works. i suspect that there might be another css that causes a problem.

Comment: Hey david, I added more info for you, please see my edit., thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not because you mouse over 16, but because your mouse went between the event divs, thereby touching the 16 div between the event divs.

See the frame below where you're over an event on top of 16 just before you cross the gap:

[image]

The way that hover works is that if the mouse is over any sub-element of the element with hover, that hover CSS will continue to be used. But the moment the mouse leaves the border-box of the sub-element AND is outside of the element with over, the hover CSS will stop working.

I bet that if you're fast and accurate enough, you can get the mouse to clip over the gap between frames and keep it open. But your users might not find that useful. ;P

---

One method that might fix this would be making sure that the event divs have no space between them. That means no margins separating them.

In order to keep your current visual without having to add too much code, you can do something like the following:

```
...
<div class="event-wrapper"><div id="e1" class="cell-data">Event 1</div></div>
<div class="event-wrapper"><div id="e2" class="cell-data">Event 2</div></div>
...
```

...where the event-wrapper class looks like:

```
.event-wrapper {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

---

Another method might be having the whole date box expand its size, but that might require some changes to how the layout works in order to keep it from messing things up.

Anyway, I hope that helps.

Comment: Hah, funnily enough, as I was editing the original you posted this. As you can see I already have an event-wrap of sorts. I think you're absolutely right - at times I CAN successfully navigate if I'm fast enough. Let me play around with this solution and report back, thanks.

Comment: So I added the margin:0 and padding:0 to both event-wrap and cell-data calsses and the gaps are still there! Is it possible my spans are the culprit?

Comment: @Tennyx - Inspect the event elements in chrome and see if you can figure out what is creating the gaps. And remember, you can have visual gaps without having any actual gaps between the elements. The only gap you need to worry about is the gap between the border-boxes.

Comment: I added a couple pixels to the heights of .cell-data and it seemed to work! I appreciate the help. Still not sure why it was giving gaps at the previous height and not now, but it's fixed and still looks good. Also, I am now running into this issue - if there's a quick fix you can think of let me know, otherwise I will probably have to make a new post for it because I am not sure how to prioritize something of the same class name with z-index: https://i.imgur.com/n6WYTY8.png

Comment: @Tennyx - I would have the z-index prioritization apply to only the events in a hovering div. In essence, only put the high valued z-index in a `.cell-shell:hover .event-wrap {  }` CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index to give priority to your cell-data elements over '16'.

Find a sample demo of it's usage below:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Add CSS property** **`z-index: -1`** into your css.

```
.cell-shell {
    height: 152px;
    width: 152px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1  // Here
}

.cell-shell:hover {
    overflow:visible;
    z-index: -1 //Here
}
```

Hope it will work for you.